# Big-O proof involving a sum of logs

Tags: math, big-o, logarithm

Prove that
[image]

I put the series into the summation, but I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you asking to prove that there is no close form solution that does not require the full n steps sum?   Otherwise, O(n) is trivial from the sum of n elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two useful mathematical facts that can help out here. First, note that ⌈x⌉ ≤ x + 1 for any x. Therefore,

> sum from i = 1 to n (⌈log (n/i)⌉) ≤ (sum from i = 1 to n log (n / i)) + n

Therefore, if we can show that the second summation is O(n), we're done.

Using properties of logs, we can rewrite

> log(n/1) + log(n/2) + ... + log(n/n)
>
> = log(n<sup>n</sup> / n!)

Let's see if we can simplify this. Using properties of logarithms, we get that

> log(n<sup>n</sup> / n!) = log(n<sup>n</sup>) - log(n!)
>
> = n log n - log (n!)

Now, we can use Stirling's approximation, which says that

> log (n!) = n log n - n + O(log n)

Therefore:

> n log n - log (n!)
>
> = n log n - n log n + n - O(log n)
>
> = O(n)

So the summation is O(n), as required.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

As a rule we know that:

[image]

Consequently:

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think that initial summation is correct. That works out to log 1 + log 2 + log 3 + ... + log n = log (n!) = Theta(n log n). Am I mistaken?

Comment: @templatetypedef, I'm talking about theta and I'm speaking of big O!

Comment: Also, how is log2 (n-1) a constant?

Comment: @templatetypedef, `i` is the variable and `n` is the upper bound which is a constant. I may be wrong, but please admit it with math!